# Flutter field has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, error-handling

i have a bool that i set to true if the account datas is right but my bool is set to late and it doesnt works

My Model:

```
bool _result = false;

Future login(String username, String password) async {

var url = "http://192.168.178.75/flutterconn/login.php";
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
  "username": username,
  "password": password,
});

var data = await json.decode(response.body);

if (data == "success") {
  setResult(true);
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Erfolgreich Eingeloggt",toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,fontSize: 16.0);
  
}else {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Nicht Eingeloggt",toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,fontSize: 16.0);
}
//print(_result);
notifyListeners();
}

Future setResult(bool rs) async{
_result = await rs;
notifyListeners();
}

bool getResult(){
return _result;
}
```

My onPressed Method:

```
context.read<LoginModel>().login(
                    usernameController.text, passwordController.text);
                print(context.read<LoginModel>().getResult());

                if (context.read<LoginModel>().getResult()) {

                  context.read<FoodSelectionModel>().loadGalleryLinks();

                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => FoodSelectionScreen()),
                  );
                }
```

My Error:

The following LateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
LateInitializationError: Field '_result@21188420' has not been initialized.

The Bool is turned to late to true how can i set it faster.

Comment: Where you have `var _result` in your code? It should be on a line which is executed before the lines in which you use it, for example where you initialize `var url`.

Comment: How do you declare `_result`? Besides, you don't need `await` at `json.decode`, and `setResult` shouldn't be an `async` function, and `await rs` is not needed either. On the other hand, `login` is an async function, so you need to `await` it when you call.

Comment: thank you guys i edited the post i solved the problem with async and await on my onpressed method

Comment: Your code does not match the error.  You claim that you declare `_result` with `bool _result = false;`, but that does not use `late`, and it is already initialized.

Answer (score -1):

i tried with putting async on my onPressed method and await it works thank you guys.

```
onPressed: () async {
                await context.read<LoginModel>().login(
                    usernameController.text, passwordController.text);
                print(context.read<LoginModel>().getResult());
                if (context.read<LoginModel>().getResult()) {
                  context.read<FoodSelectionModel>().loadGalleryLinks();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => FoodSelectionScreen()),
                  );
                }
```